# Why has vim two different text object keys for paragraph-motion and paragraph-selection?

Tags: vim, neovim

Vim and neovim apparently have two different keys for **motions** and **selections** for the text object "paragraph". I find that a bit confusing, can anyone explain what the rationale is?

E.g. I use `}` to jump to the next paragraph, but I cannot use `vi}` to select the paragraph I'm currently in, I have to use `vip` instead. I cannot use `p` to jump to the next paragraph, though.

In contrast for the object "word" i can use `w` as a motion and `viw` as a selection.

Answer (score 3):

Text objects are special motions that don't map 1:1 with regular motions. They are not meant to be the "selection" variants of regular motions, they are a supplemental set of motions with little to no relationship with the base set.

You mention `w` and `viw`, along with an imaginary "word object" but there is no such thing. You have the motion `w`, which moves the cursor on the first character of *the next word*, and the text object `iw` (for "inner word") which has nothing to do with "the next word" at all. The `w` in the text object `iw` is not the `w` in the motion `w`. In fact, and that's a common misconception, there is no `i` or `w` in `iw`: `iw` is not two discrete things put together, it is one atomic thing of its own.

Similarly, `}` and `i}` are not related in any way and you can't use `>` to move the cursor to the next HTML tag or `s` to reach the next sentence. There is, simply put, no connection to expect between regular motions and text objects.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are limited. So maybe it's simply because `p` fits "Put the text..." more than "paragraph motion".